# Command-Line Option to Open Chrome in New Window and Move Focus

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

The default behavior of running chrome via the command-line:

```
chrome www.google.com
```

opens a new tab in an existing instance of `chrome` and moves the focus from the terminal to the newly created tab.

Adding the `new-window` switch:

```
chrome --new-window www.google.com
```

opens chrome in a new window but does not move the focus.

What options should I use to open a new window but also switch focus to that window?

Note: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 too, and it works for me... When I launch Chrome from a command-line with --new-window command it opens the address in a Chrome new window, and takes focus.  How exactly are you launching the command?

Comment: Exactly as I described in the question.

Comment: if you're using a standard Windows Command Prompt (assuming that's what you mean by 'the terminal') and just running it from there as stated, then it should take focus (does for me anyway).  What version if Chrome are you using?  I'm on 33.0.1750.154 m.

Comment: Strange. I'm using the standard Windows Command Prompt; same chrome version.

Comment: Have you tried it in Safe Mode, or after disabling all 3rd party services and start-ups via MSConfig?  You may have something installed that's causing the troubles (like say, a virtual desktop manager like Dexpot)..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13740/discussion-between-isaac-kleinman-and-techie007)

Comment: I have not; can you point me to some place on the web with a description of doing this?

Comment: If I do something like that, I always have to install a waiting time until the page is fully loaded. only then follows every further processing. Maybe that will help you.

Comment: How to use same session for both monitors ? Any idea ?. I believe we cant share the same session for both monitors because of security. is that true? , then how to share the same user session for both windows

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try this one

`start chrome /new-window www.google.com`

opens google.com in a new instance of chrome.

Comment: Awesome. `chromium --new-window` seems to work on Linux. Missing from the manpage.

Comment: On Windows 10 this *does not* start a new process.

Comment: @HowardHoffman --new-window doesn't open a new instance/process. In example, you could not apply --proxy-server to that new window. It's just a detached window of the same instance, same profile, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work i Win10, power shell returns "Start-Process: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'www.google.com' "

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy add quotes to the call, in this example start chrome "/new-windows www.google.com"  this will force that to bind to -argumentList (as one arg, which is fine)

Comment: --new-window parameter works under Windows 10.  I use that parameter along with --proxy-server=xxxxx.  Thanks.

Comment: start chrome --new-window  http://url/#/  --window-position=0,0  --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1


start chrome --new-window  http://url/abc/  --window-position=2800,0  --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1

I need to share same session for both monitors and windows any idea????

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this extension which solves this bug: [Chrome New Window Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-new-window-focus/opmhcfhkhiodgapmnaolhmekmfihmecp/related).

Answer (score 1):

Give a time and it will focus on active window:

> start chrome.exe --new-window "http://hotmail.com"
>
> start chrome.exe --new-window  "http://gmail.com"
>
> TIMEOUT 1
>
> ```
> start chrome.exe "http://yahoo.com"
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you explain what exactly happens when you run these commands? In particular, why the 3rd `start` command? Also, it's unclear what you mean by *"Give a time"*.

Answer (score 0):

in 2023, with `Chrome` version Version 110.0.5481.97 (Build officiel) (64 bits), starting `Chrome` using `START` Dos command doesn't work anymore !

The solution that works on my Windows 11 PC

```
set chrome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
start "test" %chrome% --new-window "www.google.com"
```

or

```
%chrome% --new-window "www.google.com"
```

If using `START` Dos command, first parameter just after start string is **imperative** !

If I run following commands,

```
set chrome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
start %chrome% --new-window "www.google.com"
```

Windows return an error message that indicate that it doesn't find "--new-window" !

[image]

I use `START` command to load multiples `LOCAL` files in `Chrome` using following `BAT` script

```DOS
set chrome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
set dirname=%cd%

set url= 
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\TABLES.CUMUL.SOLAIRE.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\CHARTS.CUMUL.SOLAIRE.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\TABLES.CUMUL.JOUR_NUIT.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\CHARTS.CUMUL.JOUR_NUIT.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\TABLES.CUMUL.JOUR_NUIT_SOLAIRE.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\CHARTS.CUMUL.JOUR_NUIT_SOLAIRE.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\TABLES.CUMUL.EXCLUSIF.html"
set url=%url% "file:///%dirname%\CHARTS.CUMUL.EXCLUSIF.html"

start "kWh" %chrome% --new-window %url%
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try following command for the same.

> start chrome google.com

It will open Google in the new window of the chrome and also gets focused on that webpage.